# Removing outliers to calculate mean of a series/dataframe via boxplots?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot, outliers

I'm trying to calculate the average of each column (series) in a dataframe without the outliers. I used seaborn's boxplot for this task:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(50, 10),dpi=200)
sns.boxplot(x='Unit_Code',y='Leadtime',hue='Has_Weekend?',data=df ,palette='winter')
plt.xticks(rotation=90);
```

And that's what I got:

[plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPJTy.png)

I would actually love to get the mean of each unit(x axis) without the outliers. The rational behind this, and correct me if I'm wrong, is that I'd like to get the average of this feature, without the outliers, as
they skew it.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question.  (To me anyways).  I just popped an answer on for you, and tried to explain as much as possible, which keeping it light and simple.  Help this helps you get on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing outliers can be done in a number of ways. This example uses the **z-score** method for removing the outliers.

Once the outliers are removed, calculating the mean is as simple as calling the `.mean()` function on each column of the DataFrame, or using the `.describe()` function.

Without going into too much detail, the [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) is a method to determine how many standard deviations a value is from the mean.  It's very simple really, just each value, minus the mean, divided by the standard deviation of the dataset.  Generally speaking, with normally distributed data which sticks close to the mean, a z-score of 3 can be used as a filter - which is demonstrated in the case below.

[This article might be of interest, regarding the detection and removal of outliers](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba).

An easy method for calculating the z-score may be to use the `scipy.stats` module, with the [docs referenced here](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba).

For this example, I've synthesised a dataset, which can be found at the bottom of this answer.  Additionally, as I'm more familliar with plotly than seaborn, I've chosen to use plotly for plotting.

Let's get on with it ...

#### Before:

This example code is irrelevant to the issue, just plotting code.

```
l = {'title': 'Boxplot - With Outliers'}
t = []
t.append({'y': df['AZGD01'], 'type': 'box', 'name': 'AZGD01'})
t.append({'y': df['AZPH01'], 'type': 'box', 'name': 'AZPH01'})
t.append({'y': df['AZPV01'], 'type': 'box', 'name': 'AZPV01'})

iplot({'data': t, 'layout': l})
```

Output:

[image]

#### Filtering using z-score:

This shows an example of how the z-score can be calculated on each column of a DataFrame, where the *filtered* values are stored to a second DataFrame.

Steps:

- Iterate each column
- Calculate the z-score using the `scipy.stats.zscore()` function
- Filter to keep only records with a z-score > 3
- Store into a new DataFrame

Example:

```
from scipy import stats

df_z = pd.DataFrame()

for c in df:
    # Calculate z-score for each column.
    z = stats.zscore(df[c])
    # Filter to keep records with z-scores < 3.
    df_z[f'{c}_z'] = df.loc[z<3, c]
```

#### After:

Again, just irrelevant plotting code - but notice the **second (filtered) DataFrame is used** for the plots.

```
l = {'title': 'Boxlot - Outliers (> 3 std) Removed'}
t = []
t.append({'y': df_z['AZGD01_z'], 'type': 'box', 'name': 'AZGD01'})
t.append({'y': df_z['AZPH01_z'], 'type': 'box', 'name': 'AZPH01'})
t.append({'y': df_z['AZPV01_z'], 'type': 'box', 'name': 'AZPV01'})

iplot({'data': t, 'layout': l})
```

Output:

[image]

#### Sample Dataset Construction:

Below is more irrelevant code, which was used to construct the sample dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import iplot
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

mms = MinMaxScaler((0, 100))

np.random.seed(7)
vals1 = mms.fit_transform(np.random.randn(1000).reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
np.random.seed(3)
vals2 = mms.fit_transform(np.random.randn(1000).reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
np.random.seed(73)
vals3 = mms.fit_transform(np.random.randn(1000).reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
outl1 = np.arange(150, 200, 10)
outl2 = np.arange(200, 250, 10)
outl3 = np.arange(250, 300, 10)

data1 = np.concatenate([vals1, outl1])
data2 = np.concatenate([vals2, outl2])
data3 = np.concatenate([vals3, outl3])

df = pd.DataFrame({'AZGD01': data1, 'AZPH01': data2, 'AZPV01': data3})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! tried to run you code and got the following error for the chunk of code where you calculated the z_score: "Length of values does not match length of index". What's also weird is that the average seems to be around 0 after the removal of outliers. Is this correct? I have to wonder why is this not an option on seaborn as I would think someone would like to get an average without outliers pretty easily. Thanks again!

Comment: Update. My apologies for the zero mean in the 'after' example, thanks for pointing it out. Silly me had plotted the z-scores, rather than the data filtered by z-score.  This has been corrected. Please let me know how you get on.  **Changes:** 1) The filtering line has been updated to: `df_z[f'{c}_z'] = df.loc[z<3, c]`. 2) A random seed has been set, using this line `np.random.seed(73)` in the dataset construction. This will ensure the example dataset is reproducible.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Thank you! So you simply filtered out by z_score and I might use that myself. I think that Seaborn's boxplots is based on the calculation of the quartiles and on top of the IQR (75%-25%) they calculate a lower and an upper limit and mark these outliers if they extend above/below the whiskers. From your experience is the z_score better than what they're using to calculate the outliers? Btw, I learned a lot from how you code, so thank you for that. Much appreciated!

Comment: Excellent, glad it's working. May I ask that you please click on the tick in the answer to show you've accepted it?  (Standard SO practice).  There are many methods to track outliers - but yes, z-score is usually my first stop as it looks at standard deviation. Additionally, you can plot a histogram of the data and visually determine an outlier boundary ... whatever fits the purpose really.  Regarding the code, thanks. There are more efficient ways to write some of it, but went for the most readable option. Cheers mate.

Comment: Cheers mate, all the best!